# How can I change structure of my site url?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, hide

Web sites that designed with a framework, there isnt "/" at end of their address
How Can I create like these sites only with php and hide ".php" from end of my addresses?

example:
www.mydomain.com/page/1    -> this means that the user should see the page 1 but in my server root there isnt any folder with name "page"

sorry for my bad english:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is using URL rewrite support of Apache. For example, if you've a webpage called show.php?id=*numeric-id* you can map it to /show/*numeric-id* with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/show/([0-9]+)$ /show.php?id=$1
```

This configuration can be put in Apache Virtualhost configuration or in a *.htaccess* file, provided that the permissions *FileInfo* and *Options* of *AllowOverride* are activated. To activate them, add a line like this in Apache configuration:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

Alternatively, *All* activates all permissions:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: tnx can you explane this line? : RewriteRule ^/show/([0-9]+)$ show.php?id=$1

Comment: well, it's a regular expression, you'll find lots of docs on the net, but in two words the parenthesis, capture a variable which will be then referred by position as $1, $2, ... Caret ^ is start of the string, $ end of the string, square brackets delimits a char set, and in this case is the range 0-9, and + means 1 or more of the previous chars.

Comment: what is your error message, either shown or in the log. notice that the php url starts with /, I added that in successive edit. I tested the rule in my apache installation and it actually works. Also mod_rewrite must be enabled (*a2enmod rewrite*). now logging off, will check tomorrow for your answer. good luck.

Comment: Probably is a typo, but the file is called *.htaccess*, not *htaccess* and should be in the same directory of your show.php, that is your web root from the the URLs you're showing me. Also be sure that you've *AllowOverride All* in your *sites-available/default* Apache configuration file inside *Directory /var/www/* section (or your web root), and that the module mod_rewrite is enabled. I tried on Ubuntu Linux 11.10 with Apache 2.2.20 and it works. What OS and Apache version/distribution are you using?

Comment: No emails sorry. You didn't answer to my question fully, can't help you more. Read the docs of [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Answer (score 0):

What you need, is called `mod_rewrite`.

Here's a sample tutorial that can be useful to you : http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite